# Transforming Python Classes to Spark Delta Rows

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to transform an existing Python package to make it work with Structured Streaming in Spark.
The package is quite complex with multiple substeps, including:

- Binary file parsing of metadata
- Fourier Transformations of spectra

The intermediary & end results were previously stored in an SQL database using sqlalchemy, but we need to transform it to delta.

After lots of investigation, I've made the first part work for the binary file parsing but only by statically defining the column types in an UDF:

`fileparser = F.udf(File()._parseBytes,FileDelta.getSchema())`

Where the _parseBytes() method takes a binary stream and outputs a dictionary of variables

Now I'm trying to do this similarly for the spectrum generation:
`spectrumparser = F.udf(lambda inputDict : vars(Spectrum(inputDict)),SpectrumDelta.getSchema())`

However the Spectrum() init method generates multiple Pandas Dataframes as fields.
I'm getting errors as soon as the Executor nodes get to that part of the code.

Example error:

```
expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for pandas.core.indexes.base._new_Index).  
This happens when an unsupported/unregistered class is being unpickled that requires construction arguments.  
Fix it by registering a custom IObjectConstructor for this class.
```

Overall, I feel like i'm spending way too much effort for building the Delta adaptation. Is there maybe an easy way to make these work?

I read in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68985949/cannot-convert-a-list-to-pandas-dataframe-within-a-pyspark-dataframe), that we could switch to the Pandas on spark API but to me that seems to be something to do within the package method itself. Is that maybe the solution, to rewrite the entire package & parsers to work natively in PySpark?

I also tried reproducing the above issue in a minimal example but it's hard to reproduce since the package code is so complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, it turns out that the problem lies in the serialization when wanting to output (with `show()`, `display()` or `save()` methods).

The UDF expects `ArrayType(xxxType())`, but gets a `pandas.Series` object and does not know how to unpickle it.

If you explicitly tell the UDF how to transform it, the UDF works.

```
    def getSpectrumDict(inputDict):
        spectrum = Spectrum(inputDict["filename"],inputDict["path"],dict_=inputDict)
        dict = {}
        for key, value in vars(spectrum).items():
            if type(value) == pd.Series:
                dict[key] = value.tolist()
            elif type(value) == pd.DataFrame:
                dict[key] = value.to_dict("list")
            else:
                dict[key] = value
        return dict
    
     spectrumparser = F.udf(lambda inputDict : getSpectrumDict(inputDict),SpectrumDelta.getSchema())
```